# HTML5 audio not working on Chrome/Opera

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, audio, webkit

I am working for a client who wants to have audio work on iPhone so I decided to convert his files to mp3/ogg and use HTML5. There are 4 audio files and although I used the same software for conversion 2 of the files do not play on the webkit browsers. The play button is faded and the volume button has a diagonal line over it.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="index.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="index.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Does this work on Firefox or Safari browsers?

Comment: It works on Firefox and IE, haven't tested on Safari. They also work on iPhone.